# External database MVC 5.2.2 membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5, membership

I have been fighting for days with the new Google OAuth, and I *believe* I got it to work (removed and reinstalled owin), but now when I hit my site, I get:

**SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:**

**...The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory...**

Indicating that it is trying to access a SQL Express db in the App_Data directory.  I want it to connect to my existing external SQL Server

I have created a connection strings (two now).

I have tried to changing the connection string passed into the base of ApplicationDbContext to my connection string:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("myconnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I tried both pointing to a straight connection string, and an entity string.  The entity string originally errored out about tables not being included, but now it is giving me the same error.

I have tried changing the web.config to:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="[tried a connection string here as well]"/>
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

I have read hints like a line in FilterConfig.cs (that references a function that doesn't seem to exist in EF 5):

```
filters.Add(new InitializeMembershipAttribute());
```

I am just getting started with EF 5 coming from ASP.NET - The basic concepts are no issue, the framework is great and flexible, but Membership issues have been a beyond frustrating experience (and tiring that I've been at it this long)!  I have created small sites in MVC without membership before...

Are there specific web.config entries that are missing, similar to those from the old school ASP.NET membership?

I am also using [Authorize(Roles = "a,b,etc")] - do I need to specify something specific for roles, or should the change to the identity class take care of it as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the connection string to your web.config.  The base name set in the DbContext must match the name in the web.config and IS case sensitive.

Remote db looks like first line and local db looks like the second line.

Like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>        
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=0.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=someuser;Password=somepass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="mycontext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=mycontext-20150116012312; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mycontext-20150116012312.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    ... more content here ...

</configuration>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give it a shot, and report back... Thanks!  It looks similar to what I was doing, but perhaps I have just been staring at it too long.

Comment: The <connectionfactory> section is lower down in the web.config.  This should be at the top right after the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> opening tag.

Comment: Are you using the old Membership instead of Identity?

Comment: That's a good question... I think the clear shouldn't have been done.  I'm missing something, and I know it should be easy.  I added DefaultConnection and set the base to "DefaultConnection" but still the same error if I don't include <clear/>   Is this the reference from the old one?  DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet - if so, I think I may have screwed this project up when attempting to reinstall google oath

Comment: Unless you are using the old Sql Membership Provider nothing should require a clear.  You might want to look at this article [link]( http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/19/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management-Part-I.aspx) which should give you a wealth of information on the new ASP Identity and roles in same.

Comment: Looks like it is happening when the oath2 returns.  Apparently when it tries to redirect back to the main page, it errors out.  I have a theory now - the roles required for accessing the home page are not defined ("admins").  So I think this all revolves around roles?  It looks like the data is getting into the ASPNETUser table, so the connection appears to be working fine (except when it hits the [roles] attribute).